# Protobuf C++ vs Android Java

Tags: java, android, c++

I am working on an android project in which we are using Google's Protobuf library for serialization/deserialization. In the past, I have worked on Protobuf with C++. Say I have a .proto file with one protobuf object:

```
message LoginAck {
  enum LoginResult {
    OK = 1;
    NO_AUTH = 2;
    ERROR = 3;
  }
  optional LoginResult result = 1;
}
```

While generating code in C++, the classes generated for this object are derived from google::protobuf::Message as seen below:
class Login : public ::google::protobuf::Message {
...
}

Whereas if I try to generate the same code with Android, the classes are derived/extended from
public  static final class Login extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite

```
com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite<
          Login, Login.Builder> implements
      // @@protoc_insertion_point(message_implements:Login)
      LoginOrBuilder {
...
}
```

The problem is that with MessageLite type, I am not able to use descriptors which are only accessible through Message class. My Gradle build file looks as under:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.1.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

protobuf {
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src/generated"
    protoc {
        // You still need protoc like in the non-Android case
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.4.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            // The codegen for lite comes as a separate artifact
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                // In most cases, you don't need the full Java output
                // if you use the lite output.
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                javalite {}
            }
            task.generateDescriptorSet = true
            task.descriptorSetOptions.includeSourceInfo = true
            task.descriptorSetOptions.includeImports = true
        }
    }
}
```

I want to generate the java file with classes extended from Message instead of MessageLite. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research and a lot of hit and trial, I finally found the solution. The change I had to make was in the build.gradle file in the Protobuf block as under:

```
protobuf {
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src/generated"
    protoc {
        // You still need protoc like in the non-Android case
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.4.0'
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                // In most cases you don't need the full Java output
                // if you use the lite output.
                java {}
            }
            task.generateDescriptorSet = true
            task.descriptorSetOptions.includeSourceInfo = true
            task.descriptorSetOptions.includeImports = true
        }
    }
}
```

The difference here is that I had to remove the javalite plugin from the block and retain java generated code. However, in order for the new script to work, I had to delete the existing "generated" folder in my project. Now I have got the Messages.java file with objects extending Message class instead of MessageLite class which has a lot of features like Descriptors available for use.
Its a shame that this fact is not documented anywhere online. So in case someone faces this situation in the future, please make the above changes to your build.gradle file.
Thanks